# Is there is an easy way to print out form input In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a basic form where i would like to extract the user input and then display the concatenated inputs from the form

```
echo Form::open('url_encoder','GET');
echo Form::token();
echo Form::text('dest', null, array('class' => 'span3', 'placeholder' => 'Destination...'));
echo "<br>";
echo Form::text('utm_source', null, array('class' => 'span3', 'placeholder' => 'Source...'));
echo "<br>";    
echo Form::text('utm_content', null, array('class' => 'span3', 'placeholder' => 'Content...'));
echo "<br>";
echo Form::text('utm_medium', null, array('class' => 'span3', 'placeholder' => 'Medium...'));
echo "<br>";
echo Form::text('utm_campaign', null, array('class' => 'span3', 'placeholder' => 'Campaign...'));   
echo "<br>";
echo Form::submit('Encode');    
echo Form::close();
```

I would like to add something after this to concatenate the input.  In Laravel my previous way of doing this does not work.  I was setting variables that that would use `$_GET` to grab the form input.  Then I would call the variables and concatenate the variables together (ie. `echo "$var1" . "$var2" . "$var3"`).

Can someone suggest how this would be done in Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Input class](http://laravel.com/docs/input)

```
echo Input::get();
```

Comment: something like                                                                                                                                 echo Input::get('var1');                                                  ?

Comment: its up to you. Input:get() will output all the input vals. Or you can do Input:get('var1') to just get that var.

Comment: I have tried what you suggest but i cannot get the Input::get(); variable to echo out the form input.  Any thoughts on why it wouldnt be working.  This has been difficult for no reason.  Sorry to be a bother i just want to figure this out.

Comment: where are you trying to output the variable? if its another view/function - you need to include "->with_input()" on the redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dd to dump the given variable and end execution of the script.

```
dd(\Input::get());
```

This formats arrays, objects, collections, etc for better legibility.